# Connecting To Salesforce Single Sign On Via Power Query In Excel (Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, salesforce

Just wondering has anyone encountered an issue where when trying to authenticate a user via single sign on with the Salesforce Object Connector, they get the error AADSTS50178?

It tries to sign the user on with an account which does not exist in the tenant. There seems to be no facility to change this account to one that does exist in the tenant. No change account option, clear cookies etc. If anyone could help I would massively appreciate it.

Screenshot Of Authentication Screen
[image]